# Count String Values in Column across 30 Minute Time Bins using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I am looking to determine the count of string variables in a column across a 3 month data sample. Samples were taken at random times throughout each day. I can group the data by hour, but I require the fidelity of 30 minute intervals (ex. 0500-0600, 0600-0630) on roughly 10k rows of data.

An example of the data:

```
datetime               stringvalues
2018-06-06 17:00          A
2018-06-07 17:30          B
2018-06-07 17:33          A
2018-06-08 19:00          B
2018-06-09 05:27          A
```

I have tried setting the datetime column as the index, but I cannot figure how to group the data on anything other than 'hour' and I don't have fidelity on the string value count:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']
df.index = df['datetime']
df.groupby(df.index.hour).count()
```

Which returns an output similar to:

```
              datetime     stringvalues
datetime
5                0              0
6                2              2
7                5              5
8                1              1
...
```

I researched multi-indexing and resampling to some length the past two days but I have been unable to find a similar question. The desired result would look something like this:

```
datetime     A       B
 0500        1       2
 0530        3       5
 0600        4       6 
 0630        2       0
 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to do a `TimeGrouper` on the time component, so we do this in two steps:

```
v = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='30min'), 'stringvalues'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0))
v.groupby(v.index.time).sum()

stringvalues  A  B
05:00:00      1  0
17:00:00      1  0
17:30:00      1  1
19:00:00      0  1
```